# Vertical Menu Dropdown jQuery - close open menu when new clicked

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I've been making a mobile vertical nav and it's working as expected so far, the only problem is that a user can expand every sub menu and the page gets very long. I would like to be able to close any menu when a new link is clicked to expand. I have the following code

```
        <nav id="AlphaNav">
            <ul>
                <li class="clickExpand">
                    <span>
                        NEWS
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </span>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">all</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">agency news</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">brand news</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">media news</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">marketing news</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">sector news</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">technology news</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">podcasts</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="clickExpand">
                    <span>
                        TOP BRANDS &amp; AGENCIES
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true">    </i>
                    </span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">agency news</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">brand news</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">media news</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">marketing news</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">sector news</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">technology news</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">podcasts</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

And my current script that allows the menu items to slideToggle

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#AlphaNav > ul > li > span').click(function () {
                $(this).closest('li').find('ul').slideToggle();
                $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-up');
            });
        });
```

I added a very quick pen to http://codepen.io/shanekweb/pen/dNamOZ
so you can see what it looks like. I've been looking at other posts but I can't adapt it to work with my code. If anyone could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your jQuery Code to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $('#AlphaNav > ul > li > span').click(function () {
                $(this).closest('li').siblings().find('ul:visible').slideUp(); // ADDED
                $(this).closest('li').siblings().find('ul:visible').parent().find('i').toggleClass('fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-up'); // ADDED 2
                $(this).closest('li').find('ul').slideToggle();
                $(this).find('i').toggleClass('fa-chevron-down fa-chevron-up');
            });
        });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Shyam, works great. One thing I noticed is that the arrows to the right don't update anymore when the ul's close. You have any idea how to get them to match the behavior? Appreciate your help

Comment: Hi @shaneklive, I have updated the answer. Please try to use vars to strore ref. and use minimize code.